# Unable to add correct id to Div in php loop

Tags: php, html, laravel

I try to add it like **next** button will have current slider plus one and **previous** button will have last slider id so that it can go back to that slider, But i am stuck, like either i get 1+ div ahead id or -1 div behind id!!

```
@foreach($Topic->photos as $photo)
    <?$pc++?>
    <li id="no-js-slider-{{$pc}}" class="slide">
        <img src="{{ URL::to('uploads/topics/'.$photo->file) }}">
            <a class="prev" href="#no-js-slider-{{$pc}}">prev</a>
            <a class="next" href="#no-js-slider-{{$pc++}}">next</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: you should have navigation outside of the foreach loop and let javascript handle navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your array looks, you can get the index using your foreach. Then use the index to calculate the next and previous. I think it's a cleaner approach.

```
@foreach($Topic->photos as $index => $photo)
   //$index is the current iteration
    <a class="prev" href="#no-js-slider-{{$index - 1}}">prev</a>
    <a class="next" href="#no-js-slider-{{$index + 1)}}">next</a>
@endforeach
```

You have to tweak it inside the loop though depending on if the index is either first or last slide

```
//We're at the start
@if($index == 0)
   
@endif

//We've reached the end
@if($index == ($Topic->photos()->count() - 1))
   
@endif
```